# Docusign API bulk send list on template trying to discard template recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I am making a docusign integration using their API. One of the use case is to use the bulk functionality linking an send list file to an template.

```
targeting POST: bulk_send_lists/${bulkSendListUUID}/send
```

with body

```
{
    "listId": "${bulkSendListUUID}",
    "envelopeOrTemplateId": "${templateId}"
}
```

It happens that both recipients of the template and recipients from the bulkSendListFile are exchanged - the bulkSendListFile overwrite recipients of the template only if role coalesce.
That behaviour is onerous to me. It would have been much easier if the bulkSendListFile fully overwrite the template recipients/roles.
Then we could use the documents and tabulations of the template without to care the recipients/roles>

Is there an option that I missed to discard the template roles/recipient and user only send list ones?

Cause currently I have to contraint only to template with one role that coalesce with the role in my bulkSendListFile.

I would like to be able to user any template.

Thank in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, I believe this is the standard behavior to have the roles/recipient IDs in the bulk send list line up with the recipients in an envelope/template.

Tabs are defined under recipients in envelope/template definitions and if your bulk send has multiple recipients per envelope, there wouldn't be another way to correctly map which existing tabs in a template are assigned to which recipient in a multi-recipient template without Role Name or Recipient ID

In the error message description for BULK_SEND_RECIPIENT_ID_REQUIRED, it is mentioned:
If no RoleName is present, recipientID is required in mailing list's bulkCopy. Add a roleName (that coalesces with template/envelope) or a recipientID.
(Source: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/bulkenvelopes/bulksend/createbulksendlist/)

So I believe if you want to use the tabs already defined in a template, you would need the roleName to coalesce or the Recipient ID to match. You can make a GET call to the envelope/template to get the currently set Recipient ID if you prefer to use Recipient ID (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/list/)